# list pairのpattern matchingの計算

Tags: prolog

[Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming (MIT Press)](http://www.epsa.org/forms/uploadFiles/3B6300000000.filename.booksingle.pdf)

で取り上げられているパスカルの三角形（で日本語訳は正しいでしょうか）に関するfunctionにcons( list pair) のpattern matching が用いられていますがelementはどのように追加され機能するのか教えてください。以下コード全文です。言語：*oz*

---

```
    declare Pascal AddList ShiftLeft ShiftRight fun {Pascal N}
if N==1 then [1] else
{AddList {ShiftLeft {Pascal N-1}} {ShiftRight {Pascal N-1}}}
end end

fun {ShiftLeft L} case L of H|T then H|{ShiftLeft T}
else [0] end end
fun {ShiftRight L} 0|L end

fun {AddList L1 L2} case L1 of H1|T1 then
case L2 of H2|T2 then H1+H2|{AddList T1 T2}
end
else nil end
end
```

---

ShiftLeftとAddListに用いられているのが分かると思います。いくらグーグルしても探し方なのかなかなかまとまった情報がなかったので少し読み進める前に最後の切り札として質問してみることにしました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 例えば`ShiftLeft`で右端に`0`が追加される仕組みを知りたいということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、私なりの解釈はまずn=2のとき{Pascal 1}=1でH(new element)=1、始めLはnilなのでT(old element)=0さらにはcase instructionの{ShiftLeft T}=0、よって{ShiftLeft {Pascal 1}={1 0}かと

Comment: 大事なことを確認していなかったのですが、PDFの9ページあたりの話ですよね？

Answer (score 1):

的外れな回答になっていたら申し訳ありません。

まず、コメントを見る限りでは、`1`のような整数と`[1]`のような整数のリストが混ざってしまっているように見受けられます。 `Pascal`関数の引数は整数ですが、それ以外の`Pascal`の返り値、`ShiftLeft`、`ShiftRight`、`AddList`の引数および返り値は整数のリストです。

それからもう一つ、case instructionの解釈を間違ってしまっているのかなと思います。 `case L of H|T`とある時、`H|T`は新しいリストを作っているのではなく、リスト`L`を「先頭要素`H`」と「後続のリスト`T`」に分解しています。

以上を基に、コメントの`{ShiftLeft {Pascal 1}}`を具体例として見てみると、 まず`{Pascal 1}`の計算結果は`Pascal`関数の定義から`[1]`です。 これに対して`ShiftLeft`が適用されるので、`L`のはじめの値は`[1]`です。 これはパターン`H|T`にマッチして、`H`=`1`、`T`=`nil`と分解され、then分岐へと進みます。 次に`1|ShiftLeft nil`を計算しますが、`ShiftLeft nil`は（nilがパターンにマッチしないのでelseへ進んで）`[0]`を返すので、全体としては`1|[0]`=`[1 0]`となります。

Comment: リスト表記を曖昧にしていました。専門用語以外解釈はだいたい合っていると理解しました。case instructionに関するコメントについてですがもちろんpattern matching後then分岐で新しいリストが作られるinstructionではないのですか？ そうするとShiftLeft {Pascal 2}はどうでしょう、{Pascal 2}=[1 1]、Hは新たに加わった1、Tは{Pascal 1}=[1]の1、{ShiftLeft T}はつまり old ShiftLeft ということで[1 0]ですか。then 分岐で[1 1 0]ができるという解釈でよろしいでしょうか。それでいいとして、次からがいよいよ解らないのですが、良ければ解説下さい。

Comment: @ethetriple （「Tは{Pascal 1}=[1]の1」について） Tは[1]だと思います。 ところで{Pascal 1}というのはどこから出てきたものでしょうか？ またold ShiftLeftのoldというのは何を指しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。回答にあるように、またテキストの7ページにあるconsの解説によるとTは{Pascal 1}によるものでなく{Pascal 2}によるものでしょうか。old という表現も記載内容の解釈から来ています。

Comment: @ethetriple Tは{Pascal 2}の計算結果である[1 1]のtailの[1]です。 それから7ページのconsの説明ではold, newはリストもしくはその要素に対して使われているので、（関数であるShiftLeftに対して）old ShiftLeftというのは意味が通らないと思います。

Comment: 解りました（ったと思います（╹◡╹）それから、then 分岐はどうなりますか。{ShiftLeft T}が示す関数？ それともリストですか。

Comment: H=1, T=[1]なのでthen分岐は1|{ShiftLeft [1]}ですね。 {ShiftLeft [1]}の計算結果は[1 0]というリストで、 結局は[1 1 0]になります。

Comment: はい、ということは、Hは必ずリストの先頭でしょうか。L={Pascal 3}を計算するとどうでしょう

Comment: HやTにどのようにして値が束縛されるかは、8ページのPattern matchingを読んでください。

Comment: ShiftLeft による[ Pascal 4] の計算方法を教えてください。これまでは仮説が（わたしの）合うのですが{ShiftLeft {Pascal 3}}から一体どうすれば{Pascal 3}=[1 2 1]から{Pascal 4}ができるのかが元々わからなかったので。

Comment: @ethetriple Pascal関数がShiftLeftやShiftRightを使っている理由（パスカルの三角形の計算を実現している仕組み）を知りたいということでしょうか？

Comment: {ShiftLeft {Pascal 3}}の計算過程です。{Pascal 3} = [1 2 1] をShiftLeft に掛けるとどうなりますか。

Comment: 回答中で{ShiftLeft {Pascal 1}}を例としてShiftLeftの一般的な計算過程を説明したつもりなのですが、分からないですか？ これ以上個別の計算過程を説明しても意味がないと思うので、個別の場合についての説明は控えさせて頂きます。

Comment: {ShiftLeft {Pascal 3}}=[1 2 1 0]の結果{Pascal 4}=[1 3 3 1]ですね。で、ちなみにShiftRightはこの時計算結果は[0 1 2 1]です。それによってPascal 4が導かれるのであれば、やはりShiftLeft がどうして[1 2 1 0]になるのか、分かりません。後から読み返します。お時間失礼します。